# Get a specific number of images from a sorted image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sorting, cloud-cover

I want to export the first 10 images of a Landsat image collection sorted based on the "CLOUD_COVER_LAND" property. I know how to extract the least cloudy image of the sorted collection by using the "ImageCollection.first()" method, but I don't know how to access the next nine low-cloudiness images. Could someone help me?
This is the code I use to get the first image:

```
var START_DATE = ee.Date('2000-01-01');
var END_DATE = ee.Date('2000-12-31');

var sorted_image = Landsat5
        .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .sort('CLOUD_COVER_LAND')
        .first()
        .clip(region)
```

Comment: check ee.ImageCollection.limit

Comment: Thanks! That works. Do you know how to visualize different images of the sorted collection (e.g., the third least cloudy image) without having to check their dates and look them up with the "filterDate()" method?

Comment: you can filter for cloud cover with ```ImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', value))``` , then you can sort the collection with ```ImageCollection.sort(property, ascending)```

Comment: Yes, I know. I meant once you have done that, how can you easily visualize different images in the sorted collection without having to check their dates and filter based on them. But I figured out a way: adding them to a list and then visualizing the different elements of the list works well

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to obtain the desired images is to convert the ImageCollection into a List and then get the image of interest based on its index.

```
// Get sorted Image Collection
var sortedImageList = Landsat5
        .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .sort('CLOUD_COVER_LAND');

// Convert sorted image collection into an ee.List object
// Need to specify length of list, set it as the size of the imagecollection
var sortedImageList = sortedImageList.toList(sortedImageList.size());

// Get images according to its index (0 based).
var second = ee.Image(sortedImageList.get(1));
var third = ee.Image(sortedImageList.get(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the collection to a list and then loop over the image list to export each image. Then you need to complete the export in the task tab.

```js
var Landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T2_L2")

var START_DATE = ee.Date('2000-01-01');
var END_DATE = ee.Date('2000-12-31');

var sorted_co = Landsat5
        .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
        .filterBounds(geometry)
        .sort('CLOUD_COVER_LAND').limit(10)

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //convert collection to image list
  var list_img = sorted_co.toList(sorted_co.size());
  //get i image
  var img = ee.Image(list_img.get(i));
  //image name
  var name= img.get('system:index').getInfo()
  //export function
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: img,
  description: name,
  scale: 30, 
  maxPixels: 1e15,
  region: geometry
  });
```

[see in code editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/511b4439b8e5e67537ec40b83a261fbd)